# C++ template function with the using keyword and parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates

```
// I have an alias like this 
template<typename ... Args>
using msg_formatter = string(const string&, const Args &... );

// and it is returned by a class like this
class logger{
public:
msg_formatter* formatter() const;
};

// then somewhere else I wanna be able to call this
logger log;
log.formatter()("my text: %d", 123);
```

however this doesn't seems to work, any idea?
thanks a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parameter packs. A template is not a type. Functions returns (objects of particular) types, not templates. C++ does not work the way you want it to work.

Comment: `msg_formatter` is the name of a template, not a type.

Answer (score 2):

Since `msg_formatter` is a template the template arguments must be provided in the return type, but since you don't know the type that will be passed you need another level of indirection. If you have C++14 you can return a lambda from the function using `auto` return type deduction:

```
auto formatter() {
  return [](const string&, auto const&...) {/*...*/};
}
```

If you have <C++14 you can make your own struct with a `operator()` and return that instead.